# JAXB java code generation base on XSD file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm having a problem generating java source code based on XSD file.

Please notice that the XSD file was generated based on XML example.

**XML Example**

```
<resposta_importacao>
  <RetornoEnvio xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <num_apolice xmlns="compuletra">202476600001</num_apolice>
    <cod_retorno xmlns="compuletra">651</cod_retorno>
    <mensagem xmlns="compuletra">Erro de layout de dadosobrigat&#195;&#179;rios: cod_cobertura</mensagem>
    <id_validacao xmlns="compuletra">0</id_validacao>
  </RetornoEnvio>
  <RetornoEnvio xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <num_apolice xmlns="compuletra">202476600002</num_apolice>
    <cod_retorno xmlns="compuletra">651</cod_retorno>
    <mensagem xmlns="compuletra">Erro de layout de dados obrigat&#195;&#179;rios: cod_cobertura</mensagem>
    <id_validacao xmlns="compuletra">0</id_validacao>
  </RetornoEnvio>
</resposta_importacao>
```

**Generated XSD**

```
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:complexType name="RetornoEnvio">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="num_apolice" type="xsd:integer" xmlns="compuletra" />
            <xsd:element name="cod_retorno" type="xsd:int" xmlns="compuletra" />
            <xsd:element name="mensagem" type="xsd:string" xmlns="compuletra" />
            <xsd:element name="id_validacao" type="xsd:int" xmlns="compuletra" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="resposta_importacao">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" type="RetornoEnvio" name="RetornoEnvio" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

**Generated Java Class**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "RetornoEnvio", propOrder = {
    "numApolice",
    "codRetorno",
    "mensagem",
    "idValidacao"
})
public class RetornoEnvio {

    @XmlElement(name = "num_apolice", required = true)
    protected BigInteger numApolice;
    @XmlElement(name = "cod_retorno")
    protected int codRetorno;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String mensagem;
    @XmlElement(name = "id_validacao")
    protected int idValidacao;
```

The problem here is that the XML has the

> xmlns="compuletra"

But the java class don't.

I know I can just insert the ***namespace*** attribute to the ***XmlElement*** annotation but it would be nicer if the code generation could insert it for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just to answer mine own question, so that it does not go unanswered..

I could achieve this namespace difference with the most obvious solution, after thinking of it a little more. Basically using two XSD files with two different namespaces and importing them in a third XSD file.

It all worked as expected.

Thank you,

Thiago

Answer (score 0):

The `xmlns` attribute in the element defintion in the XML Schema has nothing to do with the namespace qualification of the element. This is why JAXB isn't doing anything with it.

```
<xsd:element name="cod_retorno" type="xsd:int" xmlns="compuletra" />
```

Comment: Ok, I thought that as well, that was the last test i made. I have actually tried _targetNamespace_, _namespace_ and _xmlns_.